# Image slider with multiple images needs movement on mouse flick

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having this slider showing multiple images using HTML and CSS. I am trying to accomplish following:
1. Get rid of the scroll bar
2. Enable swipe using mouse flick (should as well work on mobile)
3. Make the image link

```css
.slider{
 overflow: auto;
 white-space:nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
<img src="http://letsbefoodie.com/imagesforslider/manchow_recipe_slider.png" alt="Manchow Soup Recipe" />
<img src="http://letsbefoodie.com/imagesforslider/carrot_halwa_slider.png" alt="Microwave Carrot Halwa Recipe" />
<img src="http://letsbefoodie.com/imagesforslider/manchow_recipe_slider.png" alt="Manchow Soup Recipe" />
<img src="http://letsbefoodie.com/imagesforslider/carrot_halwa_slider.png" alt="Microwave Carrot Halwa Recipe" />
<img src="http://letsbefoodie.com/imagesforslider/manchow_recipe_slider.png" alt="Manchow Soup Recipe" />
<img src="http://letsbefoodie.com/imagesforslider/carrot_halwa_slider.png" alt="Microwave Carrot Halwa Recipe" />
<img src="http://letsbefoodie.com/imagesforslider/manchow_recipe_slider.png" alt="Manchow Soup Recipe" />
<img src="http://letsbefoodie.com/imagesforslider/carrot_halwa_slider.png" alt="Microwave Carrot Halwa Recipe" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

---

### Try using slick

Try using plugin like : https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/
You can add what ever you want in the slider and you have a lot of options

It's very simple! I have use it in lot of my project at work and it fonction perfectly!

Comment: Hi Dannick, Thanks for the suggestion. I am looking something light weight and trying to avoid any plugin. :)

Comment: Ok i understand, but i thinks if you will be doing this in pure vanilla, this will not be so light... Hum i will look up a solution for you

Comment: There this exemple : https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp
It should help you get this done! I hope ^^

Comment: Looks good to me. Just wondering what would it need to modify to show multiple images at the same time as shown in my example. Also, on clicking the button it should just move one image.

Comment: You should pour then in row, exemple image {1,2,3}(those move all together) {4,5,6}(those move all together)

Comment: See this exemple on CodePen :https://codepen.io/danaabhi7119/pen/zYYXbMY